# Display Data From Text Files

Tags: c++

I'm working on a system in which a set of data has been asked and acquired from user, stored on the text file, to be displayed, searched and eddied later. So far I could write all the functions, and data's are stored on text files, but however when I tend to read from files, I end up having an error saying "Unhandled exception at 0x0F797EA6 (msvcp120d.dll) in Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000". I'm guessing it has to do something with my pointers, but I can't really figure it out , here are the code snippets ;

function to acquire data:

```
    void get_apartment_details(){

    cout << "Apartment ID:" << apartment_id() << endl << endl;
    cin >> auto_id;

    while (true) {

    cout << "Apartment Addres:" << endl;

    cin >> apartment_address;

    if (apartment_address.empty()) {

        cout << "Please Do Enter a Name, Blank Data's Are Not Allowed!" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    }

    else if (validate_string(apartment_address) == false) {

        cout << "Please Enter Only Alphabetic Elements, Digits Are Not Allowd!" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    }

    else {

    cout << "Number Of Bedrooms: (Limited To 2,3, and 4 Only)" << endl;


    if (isNumber(number_of_bedrooms) == false ) {

        cout << "Please Do Enter Numbers Only" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    } 

    else if (number_of_bedrooms < 2 || number_of_bedrooms > 4) {

        cout << "Numbers Are Only Limited To 2,3, And 4" << endl;
        cin.clear();

    }

    else {  


        cout << "Number Of Bathrooms:" << endl;

        if (isNumber(number_of_bathrooms) == false) {

            cout << "Please Do Enter Numbers Only!" << endl;
            cin.clear();

        }

        else if (number_of_bathrooms > 10) {

            cout << "The Maximum Number Of Bathrooms Defined Is 10" << endl;
            cin.clear();

        }

        else {


            cout << "Maximum Capacity:" << endl;

            if (isNumber(maximum_capacity) == false) {

                cout << "Please Do Enter Numbers Only!" << endl;
                cin.clear();

            }

            else if (maximum_capacity > 10) {

                cout << "The Maximum Capacity Defined For The System Is 10!" << endl;
                cin.clear();

            }

            else { 

                cout << "Size (sq feet): " << endl;

                if (isNumber(size)==false) {

                    cout << "Please Do Enter Only Numbers!" << endl;

                    cin.clear();

                }

                else if (size > 929) {

                    cout << "Size Of The House Can't Be More 929 Sq Feet, Or 1000 Meters" << endl;
                    cin.clear();

                }

                else {

                    cout << "Daily Rental:" << endl;

                    if (isNumber(daily_rental) == false) {

                        cout << "Please Do Enter Only Numbers!" << endl;
                        cin.clear();

                    }

                    else if (daily_rental > 1000) {

                        cout << "The Maximum For Daily Rental Is 1000" << endl;
                        cin.clear();

                    }

                    else {

                        cout << "Weekly Rental:" << endl;

                        if (isNumber(weekly_rental) == false) {

                            cout << "Please Do Enter Only Numbers!" << endl;
                            cin.clear();

                        }

                        else if (weekly_rental > 1000) {

                            cout << "The Maximum For Weekly Rental Is 7000" << endl;
                            cin.clear();

                        }

                        else { 

                            cout << "Monthly Rental:" << endl;

                            if (isNumber(monthly_rental) == false) {

                                cout << "Please Do Enter Only Numbers!" << endl;
                                cin.clear();

                            }

                            else if (monthly_rental > 1000) {

                                cout << "The Maximum For Weekly Rental Is 7000" << endl;
                                cin.clear();

                            }


                            else {

                                cout << "Please Do Choose The Available Facilities: ( Choose 4 )" << endl;
                                cout << "1.Local Restaurant Chargeback" << endl;
                                cout << "2.On-Site Reception" << endl;
                                cout << "3.Broadband Internet Access" << endl;
                                cout << "4.Housekeeping" << endl;
                                cout << "5.Business Administration Services" << endl;
                                cout << "6.Baby Sitting Booking Service" << endl << endl;

                                cout << "First Item:" << endl;

                                cin >> opt2;

                                if ( 0 > opt2 > 6) {

                                    cout << "Please Dn Only Enter In Digits From 1 To 6" << endl;
                                    cin.clear();


                                }

                                else {

                                cout << "Second Item:" << endl;
                                cin >> opt3;

                                if (0 > opt2 > 6) {

                                    cout << "Please Dn Only Enter In Digits From 1 To 6" << endl;
                                    cin.clear();


                                }

                                else {

                                cout << "Third Item:" << endl;
                                cin >> opt4;

                                if (0 > opt2 > 6) {

                                    cout << "Please Dn Only Enter In Digits From 1 To 6" << endl;
                                    cin.clear();


                                }
                                else {

                                cout << "Fourth Item:" << endl;
                                cin >> opt5;

                                if (0 > opt2 > 6) {

                                    cout << "Please Dn Only Enter In Digits From 1 To 6" << endl << endl;
                                    cin.clear();

                                }


                                    break;

                                    }

                                   }

                                  }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

         }

    }

 }

}
```

Function to store data's in to the text file  :
      void add_apartment(){

```
    system("cls");
    staff staffobj;
    staffobj.get_apartment_details();
    progress();
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("apartment.txt", ios::binary | ios::app);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&staffobj), sizeof(staff));
    outFile.close();
    cout << endl << "\n\n Details Of New Apartments Has Been Succesfully Added";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    staff_menu();

}
```

Function to display data from text file :

```
        void display_all()
{
    staff st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("apartment.txt", ios::binary);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        staff_menu();
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tRegistered Apartments Records !!!\n\n";
    while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(staff)))
    {
        st.ShowData_Apartment();
        cout << "\n\n====================================\n";
    }
    inFile.close();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    system("pause");
    staff_menu();
}
```

showdata :

```
    void ShowData_Apartment(){

    cout << "Apartment Address:" << apartment_address << endl;
    cout << "Number Of Bedrooms:" << number_of_bedrooms << endl;
    cout << "Number Of Bathrooms:" << number_of_bathrooms << endl;
    cout << "Maximum Capacity:" << maximum_capacity << endl;
    cout << "Size (sq feet):" << size << endl;
    cout << "Daily Rental::" << daily_rental << endl;
    cout << "Weekly Rental:" << weekly_rental << endl;
    cout << "Monthly Rental:" << monthly_rental << endl;
    cout << "Facilities Availabale:" << endl;
    cout << opt2 << endl;
    cout << opt3 << endl;
    cout << opt4 << endl;
    cout << opt5 << endl;


}
```

Comment: This, `inFile.open("apartment.txt", ios::binary);` is not how to open a text file. Instead of binary files and risky `reinterpret_cast` I strongly suggest that you use text files. Text files are much safer, and support testing much better.

Comment: If the `staff` class contains anything with pointers (actual pointers, `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.) then you can't write instances of the structure like you do, because you will just write the pointers and not what they point to. I agree with @Cheersandhth.-Alf, try to create a textual file format for your data, and if you *must* use binary files (due to some requirement) then read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Since you're *guessing* where your access violation is coming from, is it fair to assume that you don't have much experience with using a debugger?

Comment: Certainly not as much as you do :) any suggestions ?